# How do I print the cell values that cause pandas pandas.DataFrame.any to return True?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The code below tells if a dataframe `Df3` cell has the same value as another dataframe cell within an array, `dataframe_arrays`. However, I want to print the cell value and the specific dataframe within `dataframe_arrays` that have the same value as `Df3`. Here is what I have tried -

```
import pandas as pd
dataframe_arrays = []
Df1 = pd.DataFrame({'IDs': ['Marc', 'Jake', 'Sam', 'Brad']})
dataframe_arrays.append(Df1)
Df2 = pd.DataFrame({'IDs': ['TIm', 'Tom', 'harry', 'joe', 'bill']})
dataframe_arrays.append(Df2)
Df3 = pd.DataFrame({'IDs': ['kob', 'ham', 'konard', 'jupyter', 'Marc']})
repeat = False
for i in dataframe_arrays:
  repeat = Df3.IDs.isin(i.IDs).any()
  if repeat:
    print("i = ", i)
    break
```

My objective is to compare my current dataframe column with columns belonging to another set of dataframes and identify which values are repeating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data is not that large, you can simply use nested `loop` with `.iterrows()` to go through row by row and dataframe by dataframe. Also, you can use `globals()` to get the variable name of the dataframe that contains the duplicate.

```
def get_var_name(variable):
    globals_dict = globals()

    return [var_name for var_name in globals_dict if globals_dict[var_name] is variable]

for index, row in Df3.iterrows():
    for i in range(len(dataframe_arrays)):
        if row['IDs'] in dataframe_arrays[i]['IDs'].values:
            print("{} is in {}".format(row['IDs'], get_var_name(dataframe_arrays[i])[0]))
```

output:

```
> Marc is in Df1
```